# How to identify the following problem given by Angular after production build?

Tags: angular, deployment, build, production

I have a large project in Angular and after production build (ng b --prod) and deployment it shows a white page and the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
    at setPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
    at i (main.5a0de34ba4bae8cec104.js:1)
    at main.5a0de34ba4bae8cec104.js:1
    at Module.zUnb (main.5a0de34ba4bae8cec104.js:1)
    at f (runtime.26209474bfa8dc87a77c.js:1)
    at Object.1 (main.5a0de34ba4bae8cec104.js:1)
    at f (runtime.26209474bfa8dc87a77c.js:1)
    at t (runtime.26209474bfa8dc87a77c.js:1)
    at Array.r [as push] (runtime.26209474bfa8dc87a77c.js:1)
    at main.5a0de34ba4bae8cec104.js:1
```

I've published a few other projects like this and didn't have this kind of a problem.

Comment: This could be a polyfill issue, please write more information like angular version, polyfills, browser you use.

Comment: More information is needed to identify it. Else, this could also be a case where you have a variable in your html which was never declared in the component.
Add more logging in the application to see exactly where this happens

Comment: This is where it shows the errorin the compiled js file:
function i(e, t) {
            function n() {
                this.constructor = e
            }
            l(e, t), <= ERROR
            e.prototype = null === t ? Object.create(t) : (n.prototype = t.prototype,
            new n)
        }

Comment: I've tried it on chrome and microsoft edge by the way and both has the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I updated my project from Angular 7.3.* to  Angular 8 and run the following build command

```
node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod
```

I was able to deploy it successfully.

Note: I had to set the maximum budget in angular.json also.

Comment: Thanks bud, this was definitely my issue too. Everything was sorted after I upgraded. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you know at which page is the error - follow these steps:

1. Navigate to `angular.json` and set `sourceMap` to true
2. Navigate to tsconfig.json and enable `fullTemplateTypeCheck`
3. run `ng build --prod --aot` (aot is important here, maybe you'll find this error during compilation)
4. If no errors, previous step created folder with your build, probably "dist"
5. Use some library to run "dist" folder. In my case I use `http-server`. 
    Run command `http-server ./dist`
6. Navigate to the page where error suppose to be. Now it should be displayed more clearly.

Comment: It failed with FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory, but I was able to resolve this with "node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --aot", but I still have the same issue mentioned above.